# Туннелирование трафика через tun устройство и libp2p

Tags: golang, ip, vpn, tunnel

У меня появилась идея для пет-проекта - p2p vpn с функцией туннелирования трафика между нодами. К примеру, есть такой проект: outline-vpn, он позволяет туннелировать весь клиентский трафик через outline server. Соответственно клиентский ip скрывается для конечных серверов. Вот я хочу сделать что то подобное, только с элементами p2p.

**Как я это вижу**

К примеру, есть 2 компьютера(ноды). С помощью libp2p эти ноды находят друг друга и устанавливают соединение. После этого первая нода может попросить вторую туннелировать весь трафик через себя. Соответственно ip адрес первой ноды скрывается. В роли транспорта между нодами будут выступать libp2p стримы.

Я не претендую на роль супер крутого сетевого инженера, т.е. у меня минимальный опыт в проектах такого рода. По этому, пока что я изучаю теорию и пытаюсь реализовать идею на практике но я ощущаю много пробелов в своих познаниях.

**Что готово**

Часть связанная с децентрализацией. Сейчас две ноды могут найти друг друга с помощью dht или mdns и наладить между собой стабильный канал для общения.

**В чём проблемы**

Часть связанная с туннелированием. Я начал с того что приложение создаёт/настраивает tun устройство и делает его шлюзом по умолчанию. Программа читает из tun устройства ip пакеты. Эти пакеты отправляются на вторую ноду и вот тут я не понимаю что мне с этими пакетами делать. Как мне направить эти пакеты в сеть? Как мне после этого получить ответные пакеты от сервера? Я вообще не уверен что я выбрал правильный подход, возможно есть путь легче?

Хотелось бы услышать как бы вы реализовали такую задачу, хотя бы в общих чертах. Мне сейчас нужно понять как это должно работать в теории. Я никогда не работал на сетевом уровне и пока что не могу осознать как реализуются такие решения.

Comment: так это же просто прокси получается. вы не скрываете первый IP. и потом за IP конечного узла всегда будет торчать. так примерно tor и работает

Comment: https://2019.www.torproject.org/about/overview.html.en